# How to create view listing all friendship for "friend1,friend2" table in T-SQL and prevent inserting duplicates?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have table defined as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Friendships] 
(
    [friendship_id] INT NOT NULL,
    [friend1]       INT NOT NULL,
    [friend2]       INT NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([friendship_id] ASC),

    CONSTRAINT [FK_Friendships_User1] 
       FOREIGN KEY ([friend1]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Users] ([user_id]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Friendships_ToTable_1] 
       FOREIGN KEY ([friend2]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Users] ([user_id])
);
```

And I wanted to create following view:

```
CREATE  VIEW [dbo].[AllFriendsPairs] WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS 
   (SELECT [friend1] as friend1, [friend2] as friend2 FROM [dbo].[Friendships] 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT [friend2] as friend1, [friend1] as friend2 FROM [dbo].[Friendships])
GO;

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX idx_dont_duplicate_friendships 
    ON [dbo].[AllFriendsPairs] (friend1, friend2);
```

In many databases it would prevent any user and any procedure from inserting (`user2, user1`) tuple when (`user1, user2`) tuple is present.

But SQL Server does not allow to create indexed view with `UNION ALL` statement.

How can workaround this limitation or achieve my goals in other way? I do not want to use triggers because my co-workers are opposing.

Relationship between friends is always symmetrical ("Alice is Bob's friend" is equivalent for "Bob is Alice's friend").

Comment: You don't need to create the clustered index on the view unless you want to materialize it.

Comment: And what's your point...?

Comment: Do you really need to materialize the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like this would work, I have not tested it thoroughly:

```
CREATE TABLE [#TestTable]
(ID1 INT, ID2 INT, UQ AS
CASE WHEN [ID1] < [ID2] THEN CAST([ID1] AS VARCHAR(30)) + ',' + CAST([ID2] AS VARCHAR(30))
ELSE CAST([ID2] AS VARCHAR(30)) + ',' + CAST([ID1] AS VARCHAR(30)) END
)

CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_NCL_TestTable_UQ] ON [#TestTable] ([UQ])

INSERT INTO [#TestTable] VALUES (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4)

SELECT * FROM [#TestTable]

-- This fails
INSERT INTO [#TestTable] VALUES (2, 1)
```

Comment: Yes, it's a good workaround, but it can fail - sum of checksums can collide easier than checksum. Upvoted anyway.

Comment: Yeah, It can. But I guess the only solution would be generate a unique value based on combination of two columns, other than using trigger.

Comment: this will yield a unique value:
ALTER TABLE [#TestTable] DROP COLUMN [UQ];
ALTER TABLE [#TestTable] ADD [UQ] AS
CASE WHEN [ID1] < [ID2] THEN
CAST([ID1] AS VARCHAR(30)) + ',' + CAST([ID2] AS VARCHAR(30)) 
ELSE
CAST([ID2] AS VARCHAR(30)) + ',' + CAST([ID1] AS VARCHAR(30)) 
END;

Comment: Can you edit your answer? I will accept it (even if it isn't beautiful).